# Re-entering US on ESTA after short stay

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I'm travelling to the US from the UK under the visa waiver programme (ESTA approved).

I'm going for 1 week, coming back to the UK for 3 days (for work reasons), then going back to the US for another 3 weeks. Is this going to be a problem at border control, i.e. are they going to think I'm trying to reset a 90-day visit even though I'm only there for a few weeks at a time?

Comment: The ESTA is valid for two years from issue (unless you passport expires,etc). To answer if your Visa allows re-entry, we need to know what citizenship you hold; are you a British Citizen? Please add the correct <country>-citizen tag. Also, are entering a tourist on both occasions, or for business reasons?

Comment: @CSM all we need to know is whether the traveler is a citizen of a visa waiver program country, and we know that.  It doesn't matter whether the citizenship is of the UK or France or Japan.  Furthermore, since it's the visa waiver program, there is no "visa." In addition, both business and non-business trips are permitted under the VWP, so it does not matter whether the second trip is for the same purpose as the first.

Comment: OP here - I'm a British Citizen, the first week is for business, the last three weeks is for tourism. Unfortunately the business trip was booked in after my holiday plans, hence the short return!

Comment: @cjst11 you can [merge your accounts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: There is no problem with this.

Comment: @Newton I don't think this is a duplicate. This question is specifically about two visits very close together, whereas the other one has a substantial gap (about two months) between the two trips.

Comment: Thought I'd come back to this after my trip and confirm that there were no problems at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They might think you're trying to reset your 90-day limit, but it is unlikely.  Even if they do, you should not have a hard time convincing them otherwise given your travel history and your booking to return to the UK three weeks after your arrival in the US.

Comment: I echo this, just tell the truth, you have nothing to hide so should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally, I had no problem being in the US for a week, back home for about ten days, then in the US again for another 2.5 weeks (also a British citizen travelling on VWP).

I can't see you having a problem, either.  Like mine, your two trips wouldn't come anywhere close to the 90-day limit even if you decided not to leave the US for those three days. That would give a 31-day trip.  You're obviously not trying to game the system by going home for three days.

The only reason the 90-day limit might become relevant is in the future. There's a rule of thumb that you shouldn't be in the US on VWP for more than 90 days in any 180-day period.  If you were to make a hypothetical third trip to the US that was very long, you might have problems if those three days you spent at home turned out to be necessary to keep you under 90 days in some 180-day period. In that case, it would look like you were trying to game the system. However, that would be a problem on this hypothetical third trip – it shouldn't be an issue for the trips you're actually trying to make.